Working with the SketchUp plugin in the cloud
Let's imagine that I have a simple plugin for SketchUp that works with model geometry and dimension creation. 
And the main goal is to work with this plugin without the desktop version of SketchUp.
With requests or in the cloud.
Are there any places where I can deploy this plugin for SketchUp and work with it? 
If you have any ideas how to implement this, please share with me.

SketchUp Web doesn't support Ruby scripting.
https://help.sketchup.com/en/sketchup-web/web-features
